# process management and stream redirection in Haskell

Tags: haskell, process, gzip, gunzip

In bash I can compose `gzip` and `gunzip` and get a command that outputs whatever I put into it.

```bash
> echo "test" | gzip | gunzip
test
```

I want to implement a function in Haskell that implements the same composition as above, using the input/output streams of the commands to compose them. My attempt is this:

```hs
module GZipID where

import System.Process
import System.IO

compress :: String -> IO String
compress input = do
    (Just hin, Just hout, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "gzip" []) { std_in  = CreatePipe
                                                                  , std_out = CreatePipe
                                                                  }
    hPutStr hin input
    (_, Just hfin, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "gunzip" []) { std_in  = UseHandle hout
                                                             , std_out = CreatePipe
                                                             }
    hGetContents hfin
```

However, when I load this up into GHCi and feed it "test" as input, it never terminates. There is some part of the process management that I don't seemt to understand. I tried to flush `hin` after `hPutStr hin`, but that changed nothing. Do I perhaps need to coerce the output to move through the `hout` pipe into `gunzip`?

Comment: Do you *end* the input stream you feed it? (e.g. by `Ctrl+D`)?

Comment: I did not, this was the issue. Thanks :) @Al.G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `hin` handle is never EOF'd/closed, so `gzip` keeps waiting for more input and never terminates, so `gunzip` never terminates either, so `hGetContents` never stops waiting for results to come back, so `hin` never goes out of scope (which would close it).

You could still get lazy strings through though with the right buffering settings, but that's fiddly and unsafe, let's not go there.

The solution I'd suggest is to close the handle manually:

```
compress input = do
    (Just hin, Just hout, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "gzip" []) {...}
    hPutStr hin input
    (_, Just hfin, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "gunzip" []) {...}
    hClose hin
    hGetContents hfin
```

Of course, a better option would be to use a library that dispenses with the manual handle handling. [Conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) should be [able to do this nicely](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/blob/master/PROCESS.md).

Comment: This was the problem, as indicated by both you and @AI.G. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also note that for very long strings this might still get stuck. The `hPutStr` ang gzip might fill the buffers in the pipes, since no one at that time is reading from `hout`. I'd be tempted to `forkIO` the put and close operations to avoid that. The rule of thumb of pipe buffering is to ensure there is a live reader at the end of the pipe before you start feeding data at the start of the pipe.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with the recommendation of conduit being "better" here. It's not like adding a `hClose` is difficult or more complicated than adding a whole new library with a whole new API and a new set of idiosyncrasies.

Comment: @Cubic hmyeah... I'm not convinced myself anymore, I thought this would probably be more straightforward and foolproof with Conduit, but it's actually kind of tricky. Perhaps [`io-streams`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams) is more suitable? At any rate I do think my manual solution is still subideal, for the reasons chi mentioned. The _should_ be some easy way to _just pipe two processes together_, shouldn't there?

Comment: I think this *is* the easy way. The issues chi mentions are with sending input to the first program, not with the pipe between the two programs. It would come up even if you simply ran `cat` and used `hPutStr hin somethingLong >> hClose hin >> hGetContents hout`.